# Deducing Lorentz representation out of symmetry type

Tags: special-relativity, symmetry, tensor-calculus

Cross-posted from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181081/deducing-lorentz-representation-out-of-symmetry-type)

Lorentz algebra can be proven to be isomorphic to $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$, so every representation can be denoted by two indices or spins, $(j_1, j_2)$.

Let's separate a tensor with 2 indices $T_{\mu\nu}$ as the sum of tensor with definite symmetry:

$$
T_{\mu\nu} = \left\{T_{(\mu\nu)} - \frac{1}{D}g_{\mu\nu}T^\lambda_\lambda\right\} + T_{[\mu\nu]} + \frac{1}{D}g_{\mu\nu}T^\lambda_\lambda\ , 
\tag1$$

where the 1st term, $\{\cdots\}$, is symmetric and traceless (provided $g_{\mu\nu}g^{\mu\nu} = \delta^\lambda_\lambda = D$), the 2nd one is antisymmetric and the last one is the trace term. Clearly,

$$
T_{(\mu\nu)} = \frac{T_{\mu\nu} + T_{\nu\mu}}{2}\ , \mbox{ mutatis mutandis for the antisymmetric term }T_{[\mu\nu]}
$$

Usually, it is written that decomposition in Eq. (1) can be interpeted as decomposition in spins such that

$$
(1/2, 1/2)\otimes(1/2, 1/2) = (1, 1) \oplus [(1, 0) \oplus (0, 1)] \oplus (0, 0) 
\tag2$$

I know how to calculate Eq. (2) starting from $T_{\mu\nu} \in (1/2, 1/2)\otimes(1/2, 1/2)$, but my question is: how can you deduce this spin decomposition by looking only to Eq. (1), i.e., by knowing the symmetry of each component of the tensor? Or in other words, if I give you some Lorentz tensor with some definite symmetry, how do you deduce what representation it belongs to?

Comment: A good start is counting the number of independent components of each tensor subspace which will tell you the dim of the rep that it transforms in. Then you can work backwards to find the reps that will have that dimension

Comment: @lux Could you elaborate more, please?

Comment: Given a Lorentz representation, you can compute its dimension either by tedious counting or by plugging the highest weight into the Weyl dimension formula. The values of $j_1$ and $j_2$ this corresponds to need to satisfy the constraint that the dimension is $(2j_1 + 1)(2j_2 + 1)$.

Comment: @ConnorBehan In the case of $T_{[\mu\nu]}$ we have 6 independent components, so $6 = (2j_1 + 1)(2j_2 + 1)$ But this is only possible if the repr is $(1, 1/2) \oplus (1/2, 1)$ and not $(1, 0) \oplus (0, 1)$. Am I counting the dim wrongly?

Comment: Maybe, the 6 indep components must be divided among the 2 possible repr? So 6/2 = 3 for each one and then we get the correct result? Is there any way to predict if the dim must be splitted between serveral repr with same symmetry type?

Comment: That's the right thing to do. The rule for predicting such a split is that you only have to do it for anti-symmetrizations of $n$ indices in $\mathfrak{so}(2n)$ algebras. This is the only case where index symmetry does is not enough to determine the irrep.

Comment: @ConnorBehan And how many splits there are when the number of indices in the tensor is $m$, i.e., $T_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_m}$? I'm thinking that always 2 since I'm imaging $T_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_m} = T^{(1)}_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_m} \pm \epsilon_{\mu_1 \cdots \mu_m\alpha_{m+1}\cdots\alpha_{2m}}T^{(2)\ \alpha_{m+1} \cdots \alpha_{2m}}$, where $\epsilon$ is the Levi-Civita tensor. Thus, $+\epsilon$ and $-\epsilon$ determine each repr for the antisymmetric term. Is this the way it works?

Comment: Yes, it's two corresponding to the sign choice for the last Cartan weight (the one where $|m|$ counts boxes instead of $m$).

Comment: @ConnorBehan Where can I get more info about this kind of things regarding reprs? Because I don't understand that of the sign choice of a Cartan weight

Comment: The crash course I've consulted the most is chapter 13 of the Conformal Field Theory yellow book. But that's mainly because I haven't searched hard enough for something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convenient way to specify a highest weight representations of a classical Lie algebra is by its associated Young tableau. Typically, these have rows which look like $\Box \hspace{-0.05cm} \Box \hspace{-0.05cm} \Box \hspace{-0.05cm} \Box$. Each row must be shorter than the row above it. The algebra you're talking about is the complexified $\mathfrak{so}(4)$. Since this has rank 2, its Young tableaux can have at most two rows. The number of boxes in a row denotes the number of indices that are symmetrized. So if you have 4 boxes on top and 2 on the bottom, you have two sets of indices which are separately symmetrized but anti-symmetrized with each other.

Let the number of boxes in row $i$ be $m_i$. There is a convenient basis, called the Cartan basis, which expresses the highest weight of the irrep by
\begin{equation}
w = m_1 e_1 + m_2 e_2.
\end{equation}
There is another convenient basis, called the Dynkin basis, which is defined by
\begin{equation}
m_1 = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{2}, \;\;\; m_2 = \frac{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}{2}
\end{equation}
where the $\lambda_i$ are non-negative integers. Incidentally, this basis shows how the Young tableau formalism can be straightforwardly extended to spinor irreps. We just allow the $m_i$ to be half-integers. **Another extension** suggested by this is that we should not really say that the number of boxes in row 2 is $m_2$ but $|m_2|$ since $m_2$ can be negative.

Now the question is how this relates to $\mathfrak{su}(2) \oplus \mathfrak{su}(2)$ which, as you noted, has highest weights given by a pair of spins
\begin{equation}
w = j_1 f_1 + j_2 f_2.
\end{equation}
Since the rank is 2, we need two non-trivial representations (called fundamental representations) to see how the isomorphism works. To make our lives easy, let the first be the spinor representation which is $(m_1, m_2) = \left ( \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right )$ in one basis and $(j_1, j_2) = (1, 0)$ in the other. Similarly, let the second be the conjugate spinor which is $(m_1, m_2) = \left ( \frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2} \right )$ in one basis and $(j_1, j_2) = (0, 1)$ in the other. This lets us figure out the change of basis between $e_i$ and $f_i$ which is enough information to always be able to go between $\mathfrak{so}(4)$ Young tableaux and $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ spins. Incidentally, the answer turns out to be that the spins are half the Dynkin labels.

Comment: Then, the working plan would be to determine the Young tableaux from the symmetry of the tensor and from this, the Dynkin labels. This ones are determine in the following way (as far as I know): the k-th Dynkin label is the number of columns with k boxes. Next, divide Dynkin numbers by 2 and then I got the spins? With this reasoning, I'd say that $T_{[\mu\nu]}$ belongs to $(0, 1/2)$ not $(1, 0) \oplus (0, 1)$, and $\{\cdots\} \in (1, 0)$ instead of $(1, 1)$. Could you elaborate a little bit more your answer and maybe apply it to Eq. (1)? Thanks!

Comment: You are confusing $SO(N)$ with $SU(N)$. The number of columns with $k$ boxes is $m_k$ not $\lambda_k$. Recalling this part of the answer, $T_{\{ \mu\nu \}}$ has Dynkin labels that are both 2 as expected. $T_{[\mu\nu]}$ is a bit of a special case it can be split into self-dual and anti-self-dual components. I just added a part to the answer about this but it works when you consider the index symmetry to be the direct sum of $(m_1, m_2) = (1, \pm 1)$.

Comment: I still don't see how you relate Dynkin lablels to number of boxes per row and that to spins. $T_{\{\mu\nu\}}$ is a Young tableaux with 1 row and 2 boxes in it and then you say it is $(m_1, m_2) = (2, 2)$ so $(j_1, j_2) = (m_1/2, m_2/2) = (1, 1)$? Shouldn't it be $m_2 = 0$?

Comment: No, I said the Dynkin labels for $T_{\{ \mu\nu \}}$ are both 2 and these are denoted $\lambda_i$. The $m_i$ count the number of boxes in each row and they are not the Dynkin labels.

Comment: But then how do you get the Dynkin numbers?

Comment: To get the Dynkin numbers from the $m$'s, you invert $m_1 = \frac{\lambda_1 + \lambda_2}{2}$, $m_2 = \frac{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}{2}$.